# Turn keybord LEDs on in assembly

Tags: assembly, io, x86, keyboard, qemu

i want to turn all keyboard leds on  by sending 0xED command to 0x60 port and send after to the same port the parameter byte which contains : 00000111b

bits 3-7: Must be zero.

bit 2: Capslock LED (1 = on, 0 = off).

bit 1: Numlock LED (1 = on, 0 = off).

bit 0: Scroll lock LED (1 = on, 0 = off).

Code:

```
mov al,0xED
out 0x60,al

mov al,00000111b
out 0x60,al
```

But it's not working

Comment: How are you testing this?  If it's inside DOSBox or something, you don't have access to your real hardware, only the virtual PS/2 keyboard connected to DOSBox.  If it's on real hardware, are you using a USB keyboard with BIOS emulation of a PS/2 keyboard?

Comment: im using usb keyboard and im testing the code under qemu

Comment: and i can read keyboard input

Comment: But does your QEMU have permission to *write* the hardware keyboard LEDs?  Probably not.  Probably your OS will let qemu read from the keyboard but not write it.  What OS are you running qemu under?  Have you looked at the QEMU docs for its keyboard emulation?

Comment: im in windows 10 and i didnt look qemu doc yet

Comment: I am using this to test my boot loader.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56515456/turning-keyboard-led-lights-on